# Error al crear una tabla con clave primaria compuesta con Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Estoy intentando crear una tabla con una clave compuesta en Spring utilizando Hibernate, lo que sucede es que me saca el siguiente error:

> 2017-09-14 09:07:55.323 ERROR 9108 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table fieldevents (is_required boolean not null, position integer not null, event_id tinyblob, field_id integer not null, primary key (event_id, field_id))
>
> 2017-09-14 09:07:55.324 ERROR 9108 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : BLOB/TEXT column 'event_id' used in key specification without a key length

El key de `event` es un `int` auto incrementable pero no sé por qué me lo está tomando como un tipo `tinyblob`.

El código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Events")
public class Event {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Size(max=200)
    @Column(name="id", length=200)
    private int id;

    private boolean active;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date creationDate;
    
    private Date endingDate;
    
    @Size(max=2000)
    private String footer;

    @Size(max=2000)
    private String header;
    
    private String image;
    
    private String logo;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "event", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Mail> mails;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "event", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference(value="event-Field")
    private Set<FieldEvent> eventfields = new HashSet<>();

    @NotNull
    @Size(max=150)
    private String name;
    
    private Date startDate;

    public Set<FieldEvent> getEventfields() {
        return eventfields;
    }

    public void setEventfields(Set<FieldEvent> eventfields) {
        this.eventfields = eventfields;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public Date getEndingDate() {
        return endingDate;
    }

    public void setEndingDate(Date endingDate) {
        this.endingDate = endingDate;
    }

    public String getFooter() {
        return footer;
    }

    public void setFooter(String footer) {
        this.footer = footer;
    }

    public String getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    public void setHeader(String header) {
        this.header = header;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getLogo() {
        return logo;
    }

    public void setLogo(String logo) {
        this.logo = logo;
    }

    public Set<Mail> getMails() {
        return mails;
    }

    public void setMails(Set<Mail> mails) {
        this.mails = mails;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }
    
}


@Entity
@Table(name="Fields")
public class Field {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    
    private String name;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "field", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference(value="field-Event")
    private Set<FieldEvent> fieldEvents;

    public Set<FieldEvent> getFieldEvents() {
        return fieldEvents;
    }

    public void setFieldEvents(Set<FieldEvent> fieldEvents) {
        this.fieldEvents = fieldEvents;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
}

@Entity
@Table(name="fieldevents")
@IdClass(FieldEventId.class)
public class FieldEvent {
    
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="eventId", referencedColumnName="ID")
    @JsonBackReference(value="event-Field")
    private Event event;
    
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="fieldId", referencedColumnName="ID")
    @JsonBackReference(value="field-Event")
    private Field field;
    
    private boolean isRequired;
    
    private int position;

    public Event getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    public void setEvent(Event event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    public Field getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(Field field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public boolean isRequired() {
        return isRequired;
    }

    public void setRequired(boolean isRequired) {
        this.isRequired = isRequired;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

}

public class FieldEventId implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private Event event;
    
    private Field field;

    public Event getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    public void setEvent(Event event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    public Field getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(Field field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.equals(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.toString();
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Busca algún ejemplo de mykong con estas anotaciones o usa algo tipo @EmbeddedId y @Embeddable (https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/) y valora que posibilidad te va mejor. Para más info: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id

Por ejemplo (a falta de saber como tienes el esquema de bbdd):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="fieldevents")
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.event",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "EVENT_ID")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.field",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FIELD_ID")) })

public class FieldEvent {

    @EmbeddedId
    private FieldEventId pk = new FieldEventId();

    private boolean isRequired;

    private int position;

    public FieldEventId getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

    public void setPk(FieldEventId pk) {
        this.pk= pk;
    }

    public Field getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public Event getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    public void setEvent(Event event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    public Field getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(Field field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public boolean isRequired() {
        return isRequired;
    }

    public void setRequired(boolean isRequired) {
        this.isRequired = isRequired;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

}

@Embeddable
public class FieldEventId {

    @ManyToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="eventId", referencedColumnName="ID")
    @JsonBackReference(value="event-Field")
    private Event event;

    @ManyToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="fieldId", referencedColumnName="ID")
    @JsonBackReference(value="field-Event")
    private Field field;

    public Event getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    public void setEvent(Event event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    public Field getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(Field field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

}
```

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/63609)

Comment: Editado como se sugiere, espero que la respuesta sea válida ahora.